# Laravel 5 database.php set to sqlite - artisan uses mysql

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, artisan-migrate, laravel-environment

I seem to be having a problem with artisan reading the default config/database.php file.

When I run for `php artisan migrate:status` - or any other migration related commands I get

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access
>   denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'

even though the default database connection name is set to `sqlite`, which doesn't require credentials of any kind.

My .env has `APP_ENV=local` and I'm running it under the local environment with PHP 5.6.2 using Mamp.

Comment: I know it's old but did you set in your `.env` 
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite?

Answer (score 2):

After calling `php artisan` I've noticed there is a command to clear the configuration cache file `php artisan config:clear` - then run `php artisan config:cache` to cache it with the applied changes - which solved the problem.